# Android app has been rejected by Google beacause of TrustManager

Tags: android

My app has been deleted from google play and then i'm not able to upload an update. Everytime they said : This app uses software that contains security vulnerabilities for users or allows the collection of user data without proper disclosure.
And they said the vulnerability is TrusManager.
I have followed they recomandation. here is my class :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your `checkServerTrusted` function is empty so no certificates are rejected, not even invalid or self-signed ones. All certificates are allowed, this is the security vulnerability. You are open to man-in-the-middle attacks.

With this implementation you do *not* follow their recommendation

> To properly handle SSL certificate validation, **change your code in
> the checkServerTrusted method of your custom X509TrustManager
> interface to raise either CertificateException or
> IllegalArgumentException whenever the certificate presented by the
> server does not meet your expectations.** In particular, please be
> aware of the following pitfalls:
>
> - Ensure that the Exceptions raised by checkServerTrusted are not caught
>   within the method. This would cause checkServerTrusted to exit
>   normally, leading the app to trust an harmful certificate.
> - Do not use
>   checkValidity for purposes of vetting the server certificate.
>   checkValidity checks if a certificate is unexpired, and cannot tell if
>   a certificate should not be trusted.
>
> You can also use a network
> security configuration to customize your app’s certificate behavior in
> a less error-prone way.

source: https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/6346016

Comment: ok than is enough to add :     trustManager.checkServerTrusted(chain,authType); ??

Comment: @SafaTelli Yes, I think that should be enough. But then your custom TrustManager has no unique behaviour so might as well remove it completely.
If that leads to SSL errors while connecting to your server, they should be solved by getting a correct certificate.